# Unable to create an extended partition

Tags: debian, partition, lvm, partition-table

Currently my host system is Debian 10.9.0, when I was first installing it I choose to use the entire disk and set up LVM (I didn't know what that meant at the time). [image: installation image]

My main issue is to set up the host system for LFS installation (Linux from Scratch). So I used minimal space for the host system (about 15GB out of 240) so I have enough space for the LFS installation.
Now the problem arises: I am not able to create an extended partition. I don't know if its because of the LVM set up earlier or not.

[image: My partition table]

[image: Extended Partition option is grayed out] 
I need to create an extended partition to be able to have more than 4 logical partitions.

Any tips for partition management for LFS? I want to build LFS then delete this host system, and maybe set it up for dual boot for windows.

Comment: This disk already has an extended partition, sda2. It can't have more than one. You can, however, add a non-extended partition. Why do you insist on an extended one? You may also be able to shrink sda2, making room for a primary partition that is not contained in sda2.

Comment: sorry, looks like i posted the wrong picture, i edited the question. The unallocated space is outside the extended partition

Comment: Nothing has changed. The disk can't have more than one extended partition. If you want to create a new logical partition then enlarge `sda2` to the right first.

Comment: finally i got it, thanks a lot. But is there a way to get sda5 out of the extended partition without data loss? i want only LFS build to be on the extended partition

Comment: I am not sure if it works, but try to remove sda5, shrink sda2, and create a new partition outside of sda2. Or simply reinstall and manually create the desired partitioning.

Comment: Expand the extended partition & then you can create any number of logical partitions. Often better not to mix LVM which normally us entire drive (except ESP & /boot if used)  and standard partitions. Also better now to use gpt partitioning which does not have logical & extended partition. See answer by Rod Smith: https://askubuntu.com/questions/629470/gpt-vs-mbr-why-not-mbr